# search for start date and ID in one dataframe and zero out data previous to the start date in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, lookup-tables

I'd like to use a lookup table to search for a start date, then zero our the data from df prior to the start date in the lookup table

lookup start date with unique ID

```
   MNI_ID   StartDate   
 0 MNWIS-13 10/1/1967   
 1 MNWIS-12 12/1/1967   
 2 MDWR-1   1/1/1968    
 3 MW-15    2/1/1968
```

df

```
    MNWIS-13    MNWIS-12    MDWR-1  MW-15
10/1/1967   12.30   22.00   1.00    17.00
11/1/1967   11.00   33.00   23.00   80.00
12/1/1967   45.00   555.00  43.00   45.00
1/1/1968    56.60   405.00  69.00   67.00
2/1/1968    45.00   33.00   20.00   29.00
```

Want dataframe to look like this:

```
        MNWIS-13    MNWIS-12    MDWR-1  MW-15
10/1/1967   12.30   0            0       0
11/1/1967   11.00   0            0       0
12/1/1967   45.00   555.00       0       0
1/1/1968    56.60   405.00       69.00   0
2/1/1968    45.00   33.00        20.00   29.00
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
mask = pd.crosstab(lookup['StartDate'], lookup['MNI_ID'])
mask = mask.reindex_like(df).fillna(0)
mask = mask.cummax()

result = df * mask
```

##### Explained

Crosstab to reshape the `lookup` dataframe into wide format.

```
pd.crosstab(lookup['StartDate'], lookup['MNI_ID'])

MNI_ID     MDWR-1  MNWIS-12  MNWIS-13  MW-15
StartDate                                   
1/1/1968        1         0         0      0
10/1/1967       0         0         1      0
12/1/1967       0         1         0      0
2/1/1968        0         0         0      1
```

Ensure the index of reshaped `lookup` dataframe matches the given `df`

```
mask.reindex_like(df).fillna(0)

           MNWIS-13  MNWIS-12  MDWR-1  MW-15
10/1/1967       1.0       0.0     0.0    0.0
11/1/1967       0.0       0.0     0.0    0.0
12/1/1967       0.0       1.0     0.0    0.0
1/1/1968        0.0       0.0     1.0    0.0
2/1/1968        0.0       0.0     0.0    1.0
```

Calculate the cumulative maximum along index axis to create a boolean mask which can be used to zero the previous values before the matching `StartDate`

```
mask.cummax()

           MNWIS-13  MNWIS-12  MDWR-1  MW-15
10/1/1967       1.0       0.0     0.0    0.0
11/1/1967       1.0       0.0     0.0    0.0
12/1/1967       1.0       1.0     0.0    0.0
1/1/1968        1.0       1.0     1.0    0.0
2/1/1968        1.0       1.0     1.0    1.0
```

Multiply the boolean `mask` with the given dataframe to get the desired result

```
df * mask

           MNWIS-13  MNWIS-12  MDWR-1  MW-15
10/1/1967      12.3       0.0     0.0    0.0
11/1/1967      11.0       0.0     0.0    0.0
12/1/1967      45.0     555.0     0.0    0.0
1/1/1968       56.6     405.0    69.0    0.0
2/1/1968       45.0      33.0    20.0   29.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this zeros out my entire dataframe.